# Show ip address in Entry Python

Tags: python, function, sockets, tkinter, command

What problem i want show ip address local system  in root

```
from tkinter import *
import socket

root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
root.title("IT")

def ipadds():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

L1 = Label(root,text="Your IP is :", font=('Arial',10)).place(x=30,y=50)
E1 = Entry(root,width = 20,command=ipadds).place(x=95,y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

Is correct use command in Entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `command` option in `Entry`. Also need to adjust `root.geometry`.  Your `Entry` code returns `None` so need to `pack` before `place`. To get an entry showing need to use `insert`.

```
from tkinter import *
import socket
root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x480+80+80")
root.title("IT")

def ipadds():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    return local_ip

L1 = Label(root,text="Your IP is :", font=('Arial',10)).place(x=30,y=50)
E1 = Entry(root,width = 20)
E1.pack()
E1.place(x=95,y=50)
ip = ipadds()
E1.insert('0',ip)
root.mainloop()
```